# Templating of the Helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to create own boilerplate helm chart and then generate from it helm charts for my micro services (which will differ only in chart names)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd need to create a package of your base boilerplate chart and then reference it in the `requirements.yaml` for other charts which depend on it.

Ref: https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#chart-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Use `helm create` command to create boiler template, then changes are up to yourself.

```
$ helm create mychart
```

Ref: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-create